# Ruby on rails captcha stop working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I got a code that uses the captcha plugin. It is a form that needs to be filled. At first it showed me the picture, below "Im a human" button and below a rich text box which I needed to paste the string witch the captcha gave me. After deleting some fields from this form the "Im a human" button and the rich text box disappeared.

I use the code: <%= recaptcha_tags %>

What happened?

edit:

Thats the code:

```
<h2>Open Account</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :validate => true, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <br />
  <%= render 'user_fields', :f => f %>

  <%= f.fields_for :accounts do |builder| %>
  <p><div><b>Account</b></div></p>
  <%= render 'accounts/form_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :password %></div>
  <div><%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %></div>
  <div><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>
 <% if !Rails.env.test? %>
  <p><%= recaptcha_tags %></p>
  <% end %>
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
<br />
<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

the user_fields and the form_fields are files where there are text_fields and those codes I edited by deleting some text_fields

Comment: Can you add the code that you were using for the form? Without it, we can't tell what kind of changes you made, or why it's broken.